# Why TypeScript complains when assigning an object literal to a generic type extending object literals?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I don't understand why the TypeScript compiler is complaining about this code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useSomething<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(): T {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>({});  // Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'.

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ hello: 'world' });
  });

  return state;
}
```

Since basically, this code works: `const t: { [key: string]: any } = { hello: 'world' }`.

Example playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=36&pln=14&pc=52#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAORTo42sDcAUHzLIAdjWARhxLM3QwAFsGEBzADwAVOOgAe+YQBNUiOAG0A1ugCeALjioYURUoC6NnMItxaAPgAUAShsNBD44OCoJOxM7PEJbWWwYpzgAXikE-HVfBFo-fhCpckoaH38Ur0R80IwYdPQfJDl0ABsmiBtWAHdoJr1WT1z8nLzQjhhkKElo-H5aAT5w4UiYGyQzSxs7B2UXODcPelTs-gWlgCYVk3NrW3tHHb3PFKNGlra2LqgevtoeIA

**EDIT**: A better example, the question is basically, is it possible to type this in TypeScript?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useComplexState<T extends Record<string, any>>() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>({});

  const setter = (key: keyof T, value: any) => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, [key]: value }));
    return state;
  };

  const getter = (key: keyof T) => {
    return state[key];
  }

  return { set: setter, get: getter };
}

interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const personState = useComplexState<Person>();

personState.get('firstName');
personState.set('lastName', 'Smith');
```

A few comments about the code:

- I want `T` to always be an object `{}` so no one should be able to do `useComplexState<boolean>`
- Ideally, `T` shouldn't be required, so if I use `useComplexState()` I should just have a generic object `Record<string, any>` inside.
- I'd like to have a default value of `{}` for the `state`.

Comment: Because you can call `useSomething<{foo: number}>()` but `{}` is not assignable to `{foo: number}`.  (Note that `T extends X` doesn't mean that all `X` is assignable to `T`.  It's the other way around) Why is `useSomething()` generic anyway?  How do you plan to call it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, I still don't fully understand the issue. I understand that `{foo: number}` is not `{}` but I assumed that'd be the case if I was defining an interface or a type with a strict set of properties, but here, what I understand I'm saying is: "As long as it's an object with a string key and anything as value, is ok"

Comment: Why would this line work then however? `const t: { [key: string]: any } = {};`

Comment: @jcalz updated the question with a better usage example.

Comment: There's a difference between saying `T` *is* `{[k: string]: any}` and `T extends {[k: string]: any}`.  The latter means that `T` may be a more restrictive type.  So if I call `useSomething<{foo: number}>()` I'm saying that `T` definitely has a `foo` property of type `number`.   The line `const t: {[k: string]: any} = {}` works because the type of `t` *is* `{[k: string]: any}`.  I don't know how to explain this any more clearly: `A extends B` does not mean that you can assign a value of type `B` to a variable of type `A`.  It's the other way around.

Comment: You're calling `useComplexState<Person>()`.  Do you think that `{}` is a value of type `Person`?  When you call `personState.get('firstName')` as in your example, what comes out?  Looks like the compiler is telling you you'll get a `string` but at runtime it will be `undefined`.  That's a problem, isn't it?  Maybe you should be using `Partial<T>` instead:

Comment: If [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVA3AFCsnIB2jwEXKDAGEKYADboAHtjzoAPABU4U-FwAmqOACV09aGrmoYUYFwDmAGjg4uATwB89gBQBKRKzhw9XI3ADaRrJWGDAy+AC6cAC8gli4+HIACjiwwDhiio5OCIQubB5e-L4h+FDRcHIA0sqSqhpwANbothAkcArOTbYAXHCVVgBu6cjovQp+leFuUfbunp4hYehOToH4vcmp6ZnTs9lwAHRHa+hWfl3hvUNiI0QueQWetDDIUAInbJ6E+Z7evmboGClcpVGp1TRdVrtTrNXqVXZzebPV7veLoc7NcKfIjsJ6AlGIOAhXoldBQKwAmC9SnA76sQjsUylEgMAiJMmofiIkjAKBGAByOBAoyJxlMZmxYhwAqFIqMJnMbAZrD+8DAHP4S3KaHQInAEmkaKSGq4zgerHVfM1aIOlKcVB5fJgguFVAels5XCWBxC9qlMtdViomBAwBgAAs3WwgA) works I'll write it up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `as T` in `useState<T>({} as T)` fixed every issue.

Comment: Yes, if you're okay possibly lying to the compiler.  `{}` is almost certainly not a value of type `T`.  At best, given your implementation, I'd say that you should be using `Partial<T>` instead of `T`.

Comment: You're technically right, it should be `useState<Partial<T>>({})`

Comment: So, if I posted the code linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063527/why-typescript-complains-when-assigning-an-object-literal-to-a-generic-type-exte/61079206?noredirect=1#comment108062194_61063527) as a separate answer with an explanation, would you accept it?  Or do you want to modify this answer yourself?

Comment: Go ahead and I'll accept it. It's the very least I can do for taking your time.